# error with train from caret package using method gam:

Tags: r, r-caret, gam

I have a `gam` model that I know works just fine in `R`, but when I try to "`train`" the same model using the `caret` package it returns an error saying that the input data columns are lists.  Does anyone understand this?

The code that I am running is as follows:

```
library("caret")
library("mgcv")

a <- gam(RW ~ s(Temp0.grd) + s(mld.grd) + s(mean_depth.grd) +
           s(land_dist.grd) + s(slope.grd) + s(npp.grd),
         data=mydata,
         family=binomial)

all.data.gam.train <- 
  train(form=RW ~ s(Temp0.grd) + s(mld.grd) + s(mean_depth.grd) +
          s(land_dist.grd) + s(slope.grd) + s(npp.grd),
        data=mydata,
        method='gam',
        family=binomial
  )
```

The first gam model works fine, but train returns the following error:

```
    Error in model.frame.default(form = RW ~ s(Temp0.grd) + s(mld.grd) + s(mean_depth.grd) +  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 's(Temp0.grd)'
```

Running model.frame.default directly on the formula also produces this error, so the problem isn't strictly speaking with train.

mydata looks as follows:

```
> class(mydata)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(mydata$Temp0.grd)
[1] "numeric"
> class(s(mydata$Temp0.grd))
[1] "tp.smooth.spec"
> head(mydata)
    RW land_dist.grd mean_depth.grd  mld.grd   npp.grd primprod.grd Sal0.grd salbottom.grd
372  1           172      -79.83889 14.70062 1124.6136          920 31.27995         32.70
373  0           157      -84.53555 14.70062  973.1954          889 31.27995         32.70
374  1           146      -91.53111 14.70062  896.5736          803 31.38220         32.59
375  1           137      -89.44222 14.70062  783.4132          719 31.38220         32.59
405  1           173     -100.87666 14.70062 1010.4898          755 31.27995         32.70
406  1           197     -104.24111 14.70062  816.1457          767 31.27995         32.70
    salsurf.grd seamounts_dist.grd slope.grd sst.grd Temp0.grd Temp100.grd Temp50.grd
372       30.36           1529.184 16.068041    1.77  6.532125  0.31340000    0.36470
373       30.36           1513.419 16.317524    1.77  6.532125  0.31340000    0.36470
374       30.68           1496.227  8.578011    1.68  6.466700  0.01937502   -0.04645
375       30.68           1479.382  8.134535    1.68  6.466700  0.01937502   -0.04645
405       30.36           1483.972 18.345858    1.77  6.532125  0.31340000    0.36470
406       30.36           1474.469 13.433269    1.77  6.532125  0.31340000    0.36470
    tempbottom.grd
372           1.58
373           1.58
374           1.23
375           1.23
405           1.58
406           1.58
```

For info, my R installation is as follows:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] mgcv_1.7-27     nlme_3.1-111    caret_5.16-04   reshape2_1.2.2  plyr_1.8       
[6] lattice_0.20-24 foreach_1.4.0   cluster_1.14.4 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-8 grid_3.0.2      iterators_1.0.6 Matrix_1.1-0    stringr_0.6.2  
[6] tools_3.0.2
```

Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 5):

When you use `train` with this model, you cannot (at this time) specify the `gam` formula. `caret` has an internal function that figures out a formula based on how many unique levels each predictor has etc. In other words, `train` currently determines which terms are smoothed and which are plain old linear main effects.

Try using the same code without the smooth term indicates in the `train` formula and see if it results in an error.

The next version of `caret` (probably around the start of the year) will give you much more flexibility to create your own formula with GAMs and other models.

Max

Comment: Thanks for this response Max! I, too, am eager to use `gam` tools like `vis.gam`, so the work would be appreciated!

Comment: Any updates on this? Since I cannot specify the formula, all variables are included as smooth terms, and there are _more coefficients than data_.